# создание пользователя с правами администратора в django rest fw

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

у меня такая форма регистрации [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо сделать пользователя с правами администратора если отмечена ячейка "Дать права администратора" и обычного пользователя в противном случае.

С фронта на бэк приходят данные [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

is_staff = True (если стоит птичка в "Дать права администратора")

По умолчанию значение is_staff = False.

Можно ли по полученной информации о is_staff с фронта в бэке  изменить значение is_staff?

На данный  момент во views.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from .serializers import UserRegisterSerializer

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })


class RegisterUserView(CreateAPIView):
    # add to queryset
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    # add serializer UserRegisterSerializer
    serializer_class = UserRegisterSerializer
    # add permission classes
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    #create method to create new user
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # add UserRegisterSerializer
        serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        print('ser', serializer)
        # create list data
        data = {}
        # Data Validity Check
        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save()
            data['response'] = True
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
            return Response(data)
```

На странице serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2', 'is_staff']

    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],  # Назначаем Email
            username=self.validated_data['username'],  # Назначаем Логин
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({password: "Пароль не совпадает"})
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

На странице models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, username, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Вы не ввели Email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Вы не ввели Логин")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

       user.set_password(password)
        # if is_staff == 'True':
        #     self.create_superuser(email, username, password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        return self._create_user(email, username, password, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)  
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  

    objects = MyUserManager() 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

решила вопрос

нужно было дополнить функцию create в  class UserRegisterSerializer

```
def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = User(
        email=self.validated_data['email'],
        username=self.validated_data['username'],
        is_staff=self.validated_data['is_staff'],
    )
    password = self.validated_data['password']
    password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

    if password != password2:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({password: "Пароль не совпадает"})
    # Сохраняем пароль
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```